# Firefox環境だとC#でSessionが取得できない

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, firefox

すみません。Firefoxで次のプログラムを実行してファイルをアップロードしようとしていますが、 '../ajax/upload_mem_file.ashx'にセッション情報が渡りません。
IE、Chromeだと渡ります。

このためFirefoxだと、「not login」のExceptionがThrowしてしまいます。

withCredentials: true　にしているのにです。何がいけないかわかればご教授いただきたいです。

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="file_entry_ff.aspx.cs" Inherits="file_entry_ff" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="ja" xml:lang="ja">
<head>
    <link type="text/css" href="../../js/ui/css/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="../../js/alert/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="../../js/flexgrid/flexigrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link type="text/css" href="../../js/thickbox/thickbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/thickbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.ui.datepicker-ja.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/flexigrid.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/messages_ja.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="../../js/uploadify/css/uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="../ajax/upload_mem_file.ashx">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="toolbar"></div>
    <%
        login_info lg = new login_info(this.Context);
        Session["shopcode"] = lg.login_shopcode;
        Session["File_Upload_Error"] = null;
     %>
    <script type = "text/javascript">

        var username = "username";
        var memo = "memo";
        var compcode = "compcode";
        var shopcode = "shopcode";
        var new_cnt = "new_cnt";
        var chg_cnt = "chg_cnt";
        var cancel_cnt = "cancel_cnt";
        var withdrawal_cnt = "withdrawal_cnt";

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#FileUpload1").fileUpload({
                'uploader': '../../js/uploadify/uploader.swf',
                'cancelImg': '../../js/uploadify/images/cancel.png',
                'buttonText': 'Excel FILE',
                'script': '../ajax/upload_mem_file.ashx',
                'fileDesc': 'Excel Files',
                'fileExt': '*.xls;*.xlsx',
                'multi': false,
                //'auto': true,
                'sizeLimit': 4000000,
                onComplete: function(evt, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                    var url = "../ajax/***.ashx
                    $("#result_view").attr("src", "");
                    $("#result_view").attr("src", url);
                    return false;
                }
            })
            $('#FileUpload1').scriptData = {
            async: false,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
                }
            };
        });

        function post() {
            $('#FileUpload1').fileUploadSettings('scriptData', '&amp;' + $('form1').serialize);
            $('#FileUpload1').fileUploadStart();
        }

        function fid(obj) {
            return document.getElementById(obj);
        }

        function onChanges(obj, msg) {
            if (msg != "") {
                if ($("#" + obj).val() == "") {
                    alert(msg + '件数は必須入力です。');
                    fid("upload").style.display = "none";
                    return false;
                } else if (!$("#" + obj).val().match(/^[0-9]+$/)) {
                    alert(msg + '件数は半角数字を入力して下さい。' + $("#" + obj).val());
                    fid("upload").style.display = "none";
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if ($("#new_cnt").val() == "" || $("#chg_cnt").val() == "" || $("#cancel_cnt").val() == "" || $("#withdrawal_cnt").val() == "") {
                        fid("upload").style.display = "none";
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                fid("upload").style.display = "none";
                return false;
            }
            fid("upload").style.display = "block";
        }
</script>
<table cellspacing="0" class="input_table" style="width:500px">
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:#7F99BE" colspan="2">
        ①　入力</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <textarea id="memo" rows="2" cols="40"></textarea><br />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="width:100px">
        １件数
    </th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="new_cnt" maxlength="4" class="cd" onchange="onChanges('new_cnt', '１')"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="width:100px">
        ２件数
    </th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="chg_cnt" maxlength="4" class="cd" onchange="onChanges('chg_cnt', '２')"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="width:100px">
        ３件数
    </th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="cancel_cnt" maxlength="4" class="cd" onchange="onChanges('cancel_cnt', '３')"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="width:100px">
        ４件数
    </th>
    <td>
        <input type="text" id="withdrawal_cnt" maxlength="4" class="cd" onchange="onChanges('withdrawal_cnt', '４')"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:#7F99BE" colspan="2">
        ②ファイル選択</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="width:100px">
        Excelファイル選択
    </th>
    <td>
&nbsp;<input type="file" id="FileUpload1" onchange=""/>        
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="background-color:#7F99BE" colspan="2">
        ③　ファイルをシステムにアップロード</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="width:100px">
        &nbsp;
    </th>
    <td>
        「アップロード」ボタンを押してください。<br />
        <input type="button" value="アップロード" id="upload" class="btn" onclick="post()" />
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<input type="hidden" id="username" value="<%=lg.login_user_name %>" />
<input type="hidden" id="compcode" value="<%=lg.login_compcode %>" />
<input type="hidden" id="shopcode" value="<%=lg.login_shopcode %>" />
<iframe id="result_view" src="../ajax/file_entry.ashx" scrolling="no" width="500" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border: 0;"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    onChanges("", "");
</script>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

■upload_mem_file.ashx

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="upload_mem_file" %>

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

public class upload_mem_file : IHttpHandler, 

System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{  

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    {

        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Expires = -1;
        string temp_location = string.Empty;
        string save_location = string.Empty;

        try
        {

            // init
            context.Session["File_Upload_Error"] = null;
            // 転送データ取得
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];
            string compcode = (string)context.Session["compcode"];
            string shopcode = (string)context.Session["shopcode"];

            System.IO.File.AppendAllText("D:\\log.log", shopcode + "\r\n");

            login_info lg = new login_info(context);
            if (!lg.is_login)
            {
                throw new Exception("not login");
            }
            string filename = compcode + "-" + shopcode + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);



            // save location
            temp_location = pdf_location(postedFile.FileName, "MEMBER_DATA_PATH");
            save_location = pdf_location(filename, "MEMBER_DATA_PATH");

            postedFile.SaveAs(temp_location);
            File.Copy(temp_location, save_location);
            File.Delete(temp_location);

            // session
            context.Session["File_Upload_PostedFile"] = postedFile.FileName;
            context.Session["File_Upload_File"] = filename;
            context.Session["File_Upload_save_location"] = save_location;

            // response            
            context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
            context.Response.Write("0");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            context.Session["File_Upload_Error"] = ex.Message + ex.StackTrace + save_location;
            context.Response.Write("9");
        }                
    }

    public bool IsReusable 
    {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`async: false`が問題なようです。[jQuery 1.8から非推奨](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)となっています。

> Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active. **As of jQuery 1.8, the use of `async: false` with jqXHR (`$.Deferred`) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as `jqXHR.done()` or the deprecated `jqXHR.success()`.**

英語版SOに[xhrFields.withCredentials will crash in Firefox if you're making synchronous AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041172/backbone-js-wont-make-cross-host-requests#comment37730116_16043390)というコメントもありました。

Comment: async: false を使用しなくてもSessionが渡りませんでした。英語版のやり方PostsCollectionも見て試してみます